# How do I run the bluebird promise performance benchmark suite?

Tags: promise, bluebird

What commands do I need to execute to run the Bluebird Promise performance benchmark?

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/master/benchmark

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running [`performance.js`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/benchmark/performance.js) directly, you'll typically use the [`bench` bash script](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/bench) that can be found in the root directory. The options are rather self-documenting.

So here are some example invocations:

```bash
node performance.js --n 10000 --t 1 doxbee-sequential/*.js
# for older node versions, you'll need the --harmony flag to run tests with generators

bench doxbee
bench parallel iojs # using a different engine that the default "node"
bench doxbee-errors node --prof # pass flags to node
```